# CSS : Align label left, text right

Tags: css

I have a text like this :

```
AAA : aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
B : bbbbb
CCCCC : cccccccc
```

I want it to be :

```
AAA   : aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
B     : bbbbb
CCCCC : cccccccc
```

How can I do this with CSS ?

Edit : Add code, although I find it useless

```
<div>
    AAA : aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
    <br>B : bbbbb
    <br>CCCCC : cccccccc
</div>
```

Comment: Add HTML and CSS, or create demo

Comment: Done, but I really don't think it was needed or made my question off-topic to not have the code

Comment: If you can add span or other elements inside the div, it is very simple to do it.




<div>
    <span style="text-align:left">AAA :</span>     <span style="text-align:right">aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</span>
    <br><span style="text-align:left">B :</span> <span style="text-align:right">bbbbb</span>
    <br><span style="text-align:left">CCCCC :</span> <span style="text-align:right">cccccccc</span>
</div>

Comment: You can't do this in CSS with only this HTML. Add a span or something around AA, B, and CCCC for instance, and set the width of this element in CSS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've to add some element that wraps the text inside it and then you can use styles on the wrapper to set the `width` of the text. I've used `span`.

```css
div span:first-child {
  float: left;
  width: 10%;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div><span>AAA</span><span>: aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</span>
  </div>
  <div><span>B</span><span> : bbbbb</span>
  </div>
  <div><span>CCCCC</span><span>: cccccccc</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on Tushar's post, if you need a flexible width, this could be an alternative

```css
div {
    display: table;
}
div div {
    display: table-row;
}
div span {
    display: table-cell;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <div>
        <span>AAA</span><span>: aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</span>
    </div>
    <div>
        <span>B</span><span> : bbbbb</span>
    </div>
    <div>
        <span>CCCCC</span><span>: cccccccc</span>
    </div>
</div>
```